# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im new to React and Redux and still kinda confused a little bit.

My goal is to render a bunch of json datas in the HTML by using GET request. I'm using react and redux to manage the state of the objects, but I believe my problem is that the data is not even there

so basically whenever someone request a URL /courses , he/she will see bunch of data in json.

I get the error in the component

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Here's the code

Action

```
export function getCourses() {
  return (dispatch) => {

    return fetch('/courses', {
      method: 'get',
      headers: { 'Content-Type', 'application/json' },
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json().then((json) => {
          dispatch({
            type: 'GET_COURSES',
            courses: json.courses
          });
        })
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Reducer

```
export default function course(state={}, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_COURSES':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        courses: action.courses
      })
    default:
      return state;
  }


}
```

Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class Course extends React.Component {



  allCourses() {
    return this.props.courses.map((course) => {
      return(
        <li>{ course.name }</li>
      );

    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          { this.allCourses() }
        </ul>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    courses: state.courses
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Course);
```

Index reducer, where i combine everything

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import course from './course';

export default combineReducers({
  course,
});
```

Configure Store , where i store the intial state and the reducer

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(thunk),
      typeof window == 'object' && typeof window.devToolsExtension !== 'undefined' ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    )
  );

  return store;
}
```

I believe why the data is not there is because i didn't call the action? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that your only reducer? Or are you combining reducers somewhere else? Can you show us where you initialise the store?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mapStateToProps` takes the root state as an argument (your index reducer, which is also the root reducer), not your `course` reducer. As far as I can tell this is the structure of your store:

```
-index <- This is the root reducer
  -course
```

So to get the courses from that state, in your component:

```
// state is the state of the root reducer
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    courses: state.course.courses
  }
}
```

Also, you might consider initialising the state of the `course` reducer with an empty array of courses, so if you have to render the component before the action is fired, you won't get the error.

```
const initialState = {
    courses: []
};

export default function course(state= initialState, action) {

    ...

}
```

Finally, you're not firing the action at all, so you will never actually get the courses, I assume you want them to be retrieved once the `Course` component is loaded, for that you can use the `componentDidMount` event in your component.

First of all, you need to map the action to a property of the component

```
// Make sure you import the action
import { getCourses } from './pathToAction';

...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onGetCourses: () => dispatch(getCourses())
  };
}

// Connect also with the dispatcher
export default connect(masStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Course);
```

Now call the `onGetCourses` property when the component mounts

```
class Course extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.onGetCourses();
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: I already edited the question with extra information. courses is definitely an array. i have test it out and it return an array of objects.

Comment: But for some reason i thing the problem is with the reducers or the action is not firing at all

Comment: @sinusGob Thanks for sharing the rest of the code! I've edited my answer, you had an error in the component.

Comment: In reducer is it correct? now there is no error but the array appear to be empty. I believe the action is not even call, because there is no event triggering it.

Comment: How do i properly do a GET in react-redux?

Comment: Guide me if possible, i know how to do POST, but not with GET

Comment: @sinusGob I believe your action is OK, you were missing the logic to fire it, take a loot at the edit and tell me how you do.

Comment: Put a breakpoint (or a console.log statement) before the test on `response.ok`, I bet it will not be the result you expected, hence your action not being fired at all.

Comment: @MarcoScabbiolo thank you for your answer, but in componentdidmount, when i console log this.props.onGetCourses, it shows a function not bunch of json.

Comment: I've edited to force the retrieval of the state from the properties in the component, that code should work. onGetCourses is meant to be a function that when called, will dispatch the action, which will retrieve the courses and pass them to the reducer, which will update it's state and pass the new state to the component, which will update itself. That's basically Redux in a nutshell

Comment: Your code does work now, but you need to edit the line where you did `onGetCourses: () => dispatch(getCourses)`, it is supposed to be `dispatch(getCourses())`

Comment: and theres no need to do the constructor and setting the state, adding the `()` is enough to fix the entire code

Answer (score 2):

its because props sometime can be undefined so you have to write a condtion like this

```
allCourses() {
     if(this.props.courses){
    return this.props.courses.map((course) => {
      return(
        <li>{ course.name }</li>
      );
    });
   }
   else {
   return []; 
  }
```

Comment: the props is undefined. Is it because my action is not firing ?

Comment: yes that can be the case, you can use the redux devtools  extension to check if your action getting fired or not , also you should pass the initial state in such a way that you can check if props are filled with data or not.